# Why is my fetch request not executing inside an event listener callback function?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api, tripadvisor

Just getting the hang of API calls and fetch and have put together the below code to fetch some info from the Trip Advisor API and log a message to the console using this info.

When I call the fetch request function it logs to the console just fine, but as soon as I wrap it in an event listener callback it no longer executes, why is this?

Appreciate any help!

```
//This is the fetch function kept in a file names request.js

const findRest = async (reviews, closed) => {
  const respond = await fetch(
    "https://tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com/restaurants/list-by-latlng?limit=30&currency=EUR&distance=2&lunit=km&lang=en_US&latitude=53.3498&longitude=-6.2603",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "tripadvisor1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": /* my rapidapi key */
      }
    }
  );

  if (respond.status === 200) {
    let data = await respond.json();
    let newData = await data.data;

    let data1 = await newData.filter(
      review => parseInt(review.num_reviews) >= reviews
    );
    let data2 = await data1.filter(close => close.is_closed == closed);
    return data2;
  } else {
    throw new Error("Could not provide results within specified parameters");
  }
};

//This is the event listener kept in a file names app.js - both files are active and no problems communicating with each other

document.querySelector(".subButton").addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("click");
  const userReviews = parseInt(document.querySelector(".userRev").value);
  const userClose = document.querySelector(".userClose").value;

  findRest(userReviews, userClose)
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(
          `${element.name} matches your search criterea and is located at ${element.address}
        To make a booking, please call ${element.phone}`
        );
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});

//HTML below

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>What Wine?</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Phil My Glass" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="An app to help you find the wine you like or something new based on your preferences"
    />
    <meta name="keywords" content="wine" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>What Restaurant?</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <form>
        <input class="userRev" /><br />
        <input class="userClose" />
        <button class="subButton" type="submit">Find!</button>
      </form>
    </main>
  </body>
  <script src="req.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/Javascript"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding async on the callback function of event listener and then call the findRest function with await.

Comment: How many `.subButton` elements are there? If there's more than 1, you need to use `.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @jarmod async function automatically returns a promise

Comment: @jarmod `findRest` is `async`, it returns a promise automatically

Comment: @YongQuan there’s only 1 button element.

Comment: try removing preventDefault

Comment: @YongQuan thanks, but it's presumably better to write `return myfunc()` than `const rc = await myfunc(); return rc;`

Comment: @Jacob tried removing preventDefault and it just resets the whole form element (which is only 2 fields and the console.log), but this stops anything being logged to the console at all. At least a with the preventDefault the ‘click’ console.log is still logging

Comment: @JoefreyR.Ramos wasn't sure this would work, but tried it and still not executing the code and/or logging anything to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Those two lines look like they could break the thread:

```
  const userReviews = parseInt(document.querySelector(".userRev").value);
  const userClose = document.querySelector(".userClose").value;
```

If either one of `document.querySelector(".userRev")`, `document.querySelector(".userClose")` is null, that will be uncaught TypeError.

Will know for sure with the HTML.

Comment: see html above added.